# How to scroll xml having two view pagers

Tags: android, android-layout

The main page has two view pagers.

Top view pager used for circular page indicator `(jakewharton viewpagerindicator)` which displays different images.

Below that I have a view pager for implementing sliding tabs with `GridView` on each tap.

Please find the xml code below

```
<ScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true">

<LinearLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".Shopping">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar"></include>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="4dp"
        android:background="#faca07">

    </TextView>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="135dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/titles"
        android:overScrollMode="never"></android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

    <com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator
        android:id="@+id/titles"
        style="@style/CustomCirclePageIndicator"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"

        android:padding="5dp" />

    <tabs.SlidingTabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="2dp"
        android:overScrollMode="always" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        ></android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>


</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

I need to implement scroll view for the whole page, tried using common `ScrollView` which doesn't work.

`GridView` has separate scroll, which is working properly, but I want a common scroll for both view pagers.

Any help would be really greatful.

Thanks.

Comment: you forget to close the scrollview

Comment: i think the problem riesd because you give the : android:layout_height="match_parent" give it to wrap_content